# AppsFlyer Xamarin iOS binding, null reference exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/XamariniOSBinding

Is anyone able to get this repo running?

I am hitting an null reference exception on startup because the tracker object is null - although this is bound as a static in the API Definition

```
// +(AppsFlyerTracker *)sharedTracker;
        [Static, Export ("sharedTracker")]
        AppsFlyerTracker SharedTracker ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue and I found out what the problem is. I was testing this using the simulator.

The AppsFlyer SDK returns `null` for the `AppsFlyerTracker.SharedTracker()` method if the app is running on the simulator. Make sure that you run the app on a real device, and that you check for a `null` before calling methods on `SharedTracker()` otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` from Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added a reference to **AppsFlyerXamarinBinding.dll** in your project's references, under **.Net Assembly**.
The dll file can be found in the project's Bin/Debug folder (you'll have to build the binding project first in order to generate an updated dll file).

Also, add "**using AppsFlyerXamarinBinding**" in your delegate.

Comment: The references are definitely setup correctly in the above repo. The issue is that there is a null reference exception. The project would not build if there were a missing reference.